# .NET library to access PE header

Tags: .net, coff

In order to automate some tasks I'm looking for a library which can let me read and manipulate (add/rename/remove sections,...) a PE header from a .NET application.
If possible, I'd rather use something that can be redistributed without source code and I'm open to commercial solutions as long as they're royalty-free and don't require licx embedding.
64bit is not required but would be appreciated.
100% managed solutions are preferred.

**Edit:** I'd just like to clarify that I'm not interested in ways to read/edit the .NET metadata of the files but the PE header itself.

Comment: Surely you could achieve what you need at build time?  Can you provide a little more insight into the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: All I can tell is that while the modification part is a minor issue and I can use a workaround, I really need to perform some operation with data gathered from DLLs and I can't do that at all without having access to several data in the PE header and especially the NtOptionalHeader.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Mono Cecil.

Or the [CCI](http://cciast.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the tool I'm writing is not targeting managed binaries and as far as I can see that makes your suggestions not suitable for my needs.